# Parsing with TBXML

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, uiviewcontroller, tbxml

So I am having an issue finding an undefined element in an element of an XML file.

I am able to parse to the element "item"...

```
<item key="ser.1.device.000001-3I67-2310.max_sampling_time" label="14459" sev="none" time="1373373210">14459</item>
```

Now if you notice, at the end of the "item" element, there is an undefined key that I need to store... How would I do so? Here is another example: (Notice the "300" that has no key to define the data, that is what I'm trying to store)

```
<item key="mod.dcc.heartbeat" label="" sev="none" time="1373475787">300</item>
```

There is always a string value in that position after the "time" key and I need to extract it....

Heres me code for using TBXML... I just need to "add" something to get that element....

```
TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSLog(@"TBXML: %@", tbxml);

TBXMLElement *status = tbxml.rootXMLElement;
NSString *statusString = [TBXML elementName:status];
NSLog(@"ROOT: %@", statusString);

TBXMLElement *itemElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:status];

NSMutableDictionary *loggerData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


do
{

    NSString *key = [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"key" forElement:itemElement];
    NSString *label = [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"label" forElement:itemElement];

    NSString *sev = [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"sev" forElement:itemElement];

    NSString *time = [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"time" forElement:itemElement];
    NSString *data = [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"data" forElement:itemElement];
    //NSLog(@"Key = %@ : Label = %@ : Sev = %@ : Time = %@ : Data = %@", key, label, sev, time, data);
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:label,sev, time, data, nil];

    [loggerData setObject:array forKey:key];

} while ((itemElement = itemElement->nextSibling));
```

***Edit***

Changing `NSString *data = [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"data" forElement:itemElement];` to         `NSString *itemValue = [TBXML textForElement:itemElement];` did the trick!!! Thank you thank you :)

Comment: Which undefined key you are trying to get? I didn't get your meaning

Comment: The one right after "time" and before breaking the item element "</item>"

Comment: check the edited answer and look at the two example elements, I made an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*14459* and *300* are not keys, that are the values of two elements of kind *item*

try

```
NSString *itemValue = [TBXML textForElement:itemElement];
```